# Can my generic class constructor infer the type from a passed-in type?

Tags: c#

I want to do something like this: `new DIConstructor(constructType)` where `constructType` is a `Type` object.

My `class DIConstructor<T>` expects that I indicate the type to construct but I'm literally passing the type as a parameter to the construction of the object.

I KNOW that I can create a constructor that takes in an instance of an object of type T but I don't want to have to construct the object. I just want that since I'm providing the type in the constructor that the generic type infers itself.

Is this possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP can test if this works by simply trying it out.

Comment: No, you cannot infer the type in a constructor.  You could however create a static method that would infer the type and creates the class for you.

Comment: create a generic static factory method

Comment: John, I understand your concern. However I have tried it and found errors which is why the question was asked in the first place. I asked this here because while I'm sure this has been asked in other ways, those ways are not searchable via google or via stackoverflow suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You cannot.
- C# does not allow constructors *themselves* to be generic, nor can type-inference be used for a generic `class`' type parameter(s) when invoking a constructor.
- Yes, I agree that it's an unfortunate *wart* of the C# language.
- But there is a workaround for common scenarios: the `static`-factory "pattern".

  - I put "pattern" in quotes because I feel the term *design pattern* is overused - and besides, most of the original GoF design-patterns are just workarounds for a programming language's limitations (...oh, wait)

---

Do something  like this:

```
public class MyGenericType<T>
{
    public MyGenericType( T foo )
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public static class MyGenericType
{
    public static MyGenericType<T> New<T>( T foo )
    {
        return new MyGenericType<T>( foo );
    }
}
```

That way you can do this:

```
public static void Main( String[] args )
{
    var foo = MyGenericType.New( 1234 ); // MyGenericType<Int32>
    var bar = MyGenericType.New( "bar" ); // MyGenericType<String>
}
```